# Trying to edit a php file to put it's content within a div

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

So I have a php script on my wordpress woo commerce site that make the top of the page look like this:
[image]
And when you click the link, then like this:
[image]

I want to put the whole content in a div so that I can add a background and border and add an h1 tag, which I will then edit the css to look like this:
[image]
and this:
[image]

Here is the php which controls the section:

```
<div class="login_section">
<?php
/**
 * Checkout login form
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( is_user_logged_in() || 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_checkout_login_reminder' ) ) {
    return;
}

$info_message  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_login_message', __( 'Returning customer?', 'woocommerce' ) );
$info_message .= ' <a href="#" class="showlogin">' . __( 'Click here to login', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
wc_print_notice( $info_message, 'notice' );</div>
?>

<?php
    woocommerce_login_form(
        array(
            'message'  => __( 'If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details in the boxes below. If you are a new customer please proceed to the Billing &amp; Shipping section.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'redirect' => wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ),
            'hidden'   => true
        )
    );

?>
</div>
```

I'm a complete beginner with php, so my question is, where to I put the DIV and the H1 tag to be able to achieve what I am attempting?

I hope I have given enough info!

Thanks very much

EDIT*********************
So i tried putting the whole thing inside a DIV, which works in all browsers except safari, which displays everything below that inside the DIV (as if there is no  tag at all.

So I'm still not sure where I should put the div tags correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by putting a div around where the function is called in the parent php file

Answer (score 0):

You should make a new class and add in the  or remove login_section and add a new yours. Create in style.css in your wordpress folder principal.

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Afraid that didn't work, but it helped me come to the solution - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I can just put the whole lot inside a div!